# HERE Map SDK configure with multiple build variants with different applicationId

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

How can I use HERE map SDK with multiple build variants with different applicationId

like - com.example and com.example.debug

There is only one input for package name in HERE map console.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Navigate](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate) or the [Explore](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore/4.7.6.0/dev_guide/index.html) Edition of the 4.x HERE SDK for Android, you can choose any package name you like and it's possible to reuse the same credentials for multiple apps.

Comment: We have Plan : [Route Guidance]. And there is only one option to add package name for Android app and one for iOS app.

Comment: Then you are probably using the Premium Edition. It has a different setup. With the new 4.x Editions, you are not bound to a specific package name.

Answer (score 0):

Package name would be unique and there is only one option for package name.

```
Name (such as HelloMap) and Organization Identifier (such as edu.self)
```

Please refer https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/3.18/dev_guide/topics/app-create-simple.html